# Python multiple levels Logging Configuration Issue

Tags: python, logging

I'm trying to set up logging in my Python script using the logging module, but I'm encountering issues with the multiple level configuration. I want to log errors, warnings, and info messages into separate files. However, the current configuration only seems to create the info log. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
import logging
import logging as infoLog
import logging as errorLog
import logging as warningLog

errorLog.basicConfig(filename='error.log', level=logging.ERROR, format='%(asctime)s - ProFilCar - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
warningLog.basicConfig(filename='warning.log', level=logging.WARNING, format='%(asctime)s - ProFilCar - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
infoLog.basicConfig(filename='info.log', level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - ProFilCar - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
```

I expected this setup to create three separate log files for errors, warnings, and info messages, but it only generates the info log.

I appreciate for your help!